# Nodejs penetration testing

Tags: node.js, security

Are there any pen-testing agencies that tests nodejs applications? And are there any good tools with wich you can do it yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of what platform you choose a lot of the same vulnerabilities are found.  I recommend the open source project [skipfish](http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/) or a service like [Sitewatch](https://sitewat.ch/en/About).  Skipfish doesn't have a JavaScript interpreter,  so if you use client side js heavily then you should go with the open source [Grendel-Scan](http://www.grendel-scan.com/).

Comment: Sitewatch is apparently no longer in operation and grendel-scan.com is a cybersquatter domain, you can find the Grendel scan on this page however http://www.securitytube.net/video/3614

Answer (score 1):

Zaproxy, is a great tool for web application pentest http://sourceforge.net/projects/zaproxy/files/

Answer (score 0):

A bit late in the day, however www.ZeroDayLab.com specialise in app security scans like this.